# Change allowed maximum simultaneous TCP connections of Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

According to this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/network

Edge can do a maximum of 6 simultaneous TCP connections per hostname.
In IE it was possible to change this. Can I change this for Edge and where is the registry can this be found (this is how it was done in IE)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to follow steps below to disable the connection limit.

(1) Type **Regedit** in **Run** window to open registry editor.

(2) navigate to location below.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters

(3) Add new **DWORD(32 bit)** value.

(4) Name it as **EnableConnectionRateLimiting**

(5) Double click on it and set it value to **0**.

[image]

Note:- User can also set the maximum desired limit for connections.

Comment: `EnableConnectionRateLimiting` has little to do with maximum connections per server: it is related with half-open connections, usually related with the rate at which connections are being made within a single burst. Windows XP SP2 did this in a non-configurable way.

Comment: Perhaps the key you want is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\MaxUserPort:DWORD  this article says it's ~4000 by default (+1024 privilaged ports) https://docs.eggplantsoftware.com/epp/9.0.0/ePP/advovercoming_tcpip_connection_li.htm